# multiple if/and statement returning #value! error

Tags: excel, if-statement

I need help with a statement that is returning `#value!`

I need to my statement to work out if both `K4` and `I4` are blank then it will return the value in `H4`.  However if only `K4` is blank then I want it to show the value of `I4` minus `H4`.

This is what I have but it isn't working.

```
=IF(AND(K4="",I4=""),H4),IF(K4="",I4-H4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not nested your formulas properly. Also for the second condition, it is better to use "<>" (not equal to) to test whether I4 is not blank.

```
=IF(AND(K4="",I4=""),H4,IF(I4<>"",I4-H4,IF(K4<>"",K4-H4,"")))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it is really appreciated.  I forgot to say that I also need the statement to show  if K4 contains a number then it will show k4-h4.  This is proving to be a mind boggler for me!

Comment: I tried adding on if(k4>0,k4-h4) to the end of your statement but it didn't work.

Comment: It is working only if k4 is not populated.  If K4 has a number it is returning a #Value! error

Comment: Works fine when I am testing it

Comment: I figured what the problem was.  Your statement is perfect.  Thank you so much for all your help.  It is very much appreciated and saved me a lot of stress you are a star!!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(K4 = "", I4 = ""), H4, IF(K4 = "", I4-H4, ""))
```

Also please check on how to use the nested [`IF function`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php)

Comment: Your formula is returning I4-H4 irrespective of whether it is only K4 which is blank or both K4 and I4 are blank.